# Divs, absolute positioning, white space

Tags: css

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="title"></div>
        <div id="mainimage">
            <img src="mainimage.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%;">
        content here...
    </div>
</body>
```

http://susiebushphotography.com/about.html

thanks to the community here im starting to learn not to use absolute positioning- but this layout was done by someone before i started here-- so is there an easy way to remove the white space below the lion so i can use this as the ABOUT page? or do i have to redo the entire CSS layout?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the original with this to remove the space below the lion,

```
#wrapper {
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 685px;
}

#title{
  position:absolute;
  top: 15px;
  width: 235px;
  height:265px;
  background-image:url(title.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  display:block;
}

#mainimage{
  position:absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 235px;
  width: 450px;
  height:265px;
  display:block;
}
```

This is just a quickfix kinda stuff, and a work around.

**Notice: Only tried on FF 3.5.6.**

Comment: change the css master file or put this somewhere in the about page? if i put it in the master file will it affect the other pages?

Comment: @adam: Yes, put it only in the about page header.

Comment: @gs thanks-- i marked the q as answered and will try and move on- but i dont think it worked and im using the right version of FF

i copied the code as is, into the header then i hadded style tags above and below-- neither changed anything

Comment: These CSS classes is under your `style.css`. You can directly change those, but that might affect your other pages. So, you might like to add it as a separate one for `about` page. Or you might want to fix the other pages accordingly, instead, if those are not many.